# What can cause some renderings to not appear even after being published?

Tags: presentation

I have a Sitecore 9.1 dev instance. I added a non-cached View Rendering to the Default Layout (using Presentation Details), specifying "Content" as Placeholder.

I reset IIS, cleared Sitecore cache, logged in and out, added read access to both the item and the Rendering under the Default/Everyone role - it won't show up.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99874/discussion-on-question-by-emanuele-ciriachi-what-can-cause-some-renderings-to-no).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was a permission issue. The roles that I had setup were missing from the instance - apparently, migrating Core, Master and Web does not also migrate custom Roles.

After packaging and importing my custom Roles, my renderings showed up.